# Problems with pagination for a custom post type in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

My pagination links are failing for a custom post type.

the page reloads root/cat/page/2/ but this has no effect on the displayed posts. Flushing the permalink structure has no effect so my guess is the problem is in the query.

```
<?php 
$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 10;
$temp = $wp_query;
$wp_query= null;
$wp_query = new WP_Query();
$wp_query->query(array( 'post_type' => 'press',
                                'orderby'   => 'post_date',
                                'posts_per_page' => $paged,
                                ));
while ($wp_query->have_posts()) : $wp_query->the_post(); 



    // The following determines what the post format is and shows the correct file accordingly
    $format = get_post_format();
    get_template_part( '/lib/includes/post-formats/'.$format );

    if($format == '')
    get_template_part( '/lib/includes/post-formats/standard' );

endwhile;


global $wp_query;

$big = 999999999; // need an unlikely integer

echo paginate_links( array(
    'base' => str_replace( $big, '%#%', get_pagenum_link( $big ) ),
    'format' => '?paged=%#%',
    'current' => max( 1, get_query_var('paged') ),
    'total' => $wp_query->max_num_pages
) );

$wp_query = null; $wp_query = $temp; ?>
```

Comment: I recently helped solve an issue like this one here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18157591/wordpress-pagination-in-custom-loop-not-working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`posts_per_page` and `showposts` is essentially the same. These arguments define the amount of posts appearing on a page. `showposts` is deprecated and `posts_per_page` should be used instead. The relevant parameter for pagination is `paged`.

Hence the query arguments should look like this:

```
array(
    'post_type' => 'press',
    'orderby'   => 'post_date',
    'posts_per_page' => 10,
    'paged' => $paged
)
```

For reference, see the codex on [WP_Query, pagination parameters](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Pagination_Parameters).

Comment: I thought they may be redundant, but removing those parameters doesn't fix the problem.

Comment: Did you add the `paged` parameter? And, seeing that you commented it out as well, the `$paged` variable is necessary.

Comment: Yes, but this results in some very wierd behavior, check out the site now.

Answer (score 0):

The answer turned out to be

```
'orderby'   => 'date',
```

rather than

```
'orderby'   => 'post_date',
```